# Preparing custom action bar

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, customization

I am trying to get exactly like the below image.

[image]

But I am able to get the below one right now. Here I have two questions.

**1)** How to make this `actionbar` to be worked on all activities instead of single activity that I am inflating now.

**2)** The above image seems like elevated layout bar, but mine looks like a normal panel. Can some one please help me how to achieve these? Code snippets are appreciated.

**My current output:**

[image]

**My layout code to inflate to actionbar:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/ab_customshape" >

    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/homeicon"
            android:layout_width="40sp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >
     </ImageButton>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="My Title"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <ImageButton 
        android:id="@+id/rightbutton"
            android:layout_width="40sp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Activity code snippets:**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        initActionBar();
    }

    private void initActionBar() {
        mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar, null);
        mTitleTextView = (TextView) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.title_text);
        mTitleTextView.setText("My Own Title");
        mActionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    }
```

**@drawable/ab_customshape:**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="-90"
        android:endColor="#DD2ECCFA"
        android:startColor="#DD000000"
        android:type="linear" />

</shape>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) How to make this actionbar to be worked on all activities instead of single activity that I am inflating now.

Add below code to your style.xml.

```
<style name="Theme.Styled" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeCloseDrawable">@drawable/collapse_button</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
</style>
<style name="Widget.Styled.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="background">@drawable/ab_customshape</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_customshape</item>

</style>
```

Then set this as your app theme in your manifest like,

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Styled" > //Here we set the theme
```

And try to add buttons to your actionbar like this,

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {


    menu.add(0, HOMEBUTTON, 0, "Home").setIcon(R.drawable.home_button)

    .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);

    return true;
}
```

[image]

and 9 patch here [image]

Comment: What do you meant by elevated  layout bar? Please explain then only I can help.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But as per your code the action items and home icons are displayed according to the actionbar style, I mean only if there is room available. Please correct me if I am wrong. for the second question, as you can see, the actionbar layout seems that it looks an elevated when compared to the screen below the actionbar. See clearly in the first image in my post.

Comment: You can set your buttons to show always like, .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);

Comment: Try swapping your gradient colors in actionbar.Then it will get an elevated look(Lighter color always sholud be at start and darker at last).Am I correct? Or do you want to add shadow below your actionbar?

Comment: Try using my attached image as Actionbar background

Comment: Yeah. Thanks. It somewhat did it. But the way I have chosen color codes don't look good as in the first image. can you please check my drawable/ab_customshape.xml? Am I missing something?

Comment: I already swapped those two colors. I think my way of color selection and adding gradients is bad ;)

Comment: Then try my attached image file.

Comment: +1 for your time. But I unable to try the attached image. It is unable to get downloaded. Can you please come [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19132/java-and-android-era). This says to avoid long comments.